# Maclaurin series for $\frac{\sin{x}}{1-2x}$

Tags: taylor-expansion

The function is $$ \frac{\sin{x}}{1-2x},$$

we have to find its Maclaurin series using composite functions

I know the other method of manually calculating the derivatives,but the question specifically asks for composite functions.
I tried taking the Maclaurin series of sin x and then divide by 1 - 2x, but that didn't give me the right answer
so how do I use composite functions to calculate this?

Comment: Please show us your work. This is the usage on this site.

Comment: Is there a constraint on $x$ given with this problem?

Comment: I do not see why division by increasing powers of $x$ would not give you the right answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to expand $(1-2x)^{-1}$ as well. (I am not sure what you mean by using composite functions but this should suffice.

$\sin(x)=x-x^3/3!+x^5/5!....=x-x^3/6+x^5/120-...$

and

$(1-2x)^{-1}=1+(-1)(-2x)+\frac{(-1)(-2)}{2!}(-2x)^2...=1+2x+4x^2+...$

Multiply these out to get

$\frac{\sin(x)}{1-2x}=x+2x^2+4x^3-\frac{1}{6}x^3+...=x+2x^2+\frac{23}{6} x^3+...$

And so on...

Comment: ohh yes i didnt expand 1/1-2x.. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Another method consists performing the division *by increasing power order* of the expansion of $\sin x$ by $1-2x$, up to the required order of expansion:

\begin{array}{rclrrc}
&&x+2x^2&{}+\frac{23}6x^3&{}+\frac{23}3x^4&{}+\cdots\\
\llap{1-2x} &\!\!\llap{\Big)}\!\!&x&{}-\frac16x^3&+\frac1{120}x^5&{}+\cdots\\
&&\llap-x+2x^2&\\
 \hline
&&2x^2{}&{}-\frac16x^3&{}+\frac1{120}x^5&{}+\cdots&{}+\cdots\\
&&-2x^2&{}+4x^3 \\
\hline
&&&\frac{23}6x^3&{}+\frac1{120}x^5&{}+\cdots \\
&&&{}-\frac{23}6x^3&{}+\frac{23}{3}x^4
\end{array}